# Input tipo file como read-only

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando setar como read-only um input tipo file ao clicar no submit, mas da forma abaixo não deu certo.
Alguma sugestão?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#salvar").on('click', function() {
       $('#arquivo').prop('readonly', true);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Troque a propriedade `readonly` por `disabled`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#salvar").on('click', function() {
       $('#arquivo').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/51emkmg2/

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas dessa forma ele "perde" o arquivo e o mesmo nem vai para a proxima tela. Estou testando um .hide().

Answer (score 1):

Para desativar um input-file utilize a propridade [disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_disabled.asp)

**Exemplo em JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("myFile").disabled = true;
```

**Exemplo com jQuery**

```
$('myFile').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas dessa forma ele "perde" o arquivo e o mesmo nem vai para a proxima tela. Estou testando um .hide().